# DataGridTextColum binding StringFormat

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind a string in my view model to the StringFormat property of the DataGridTextColumn. But, what I have below is not working. Is there a way to do this without using converters or resources? If not, what's the easiest way to do it?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat={Binding DateFormat}}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind anything to properties of `Binding` because the `Binding` class doesn't inherit from `DependencyObject`.

Controls derived from `ContentControl` (e.g. `Label`) have a `ContentStringFormat` property that you can bind. That would solve your problem in this case if `DataGridTextColumn` were derived from `ContentControl` but it isn't.

You could make it a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `DataTemplate` containing a `Label`, and bind `Label.ContentStringFormat` to your `DateFormat` property:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date Template">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label
                Content="{Binding Date}"
                ContentStringFormat="{Binding DataContext.DateFormat, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But that doesn't update when I change the viewmodel's `DateFormat` property. I don't know why not, possibly I did something wrong.

That leaves us with a multi-value converter. That does update when I change the viewmodel's `DateFormat` property (two adjacent columns, one updates and the other doesn't -- so don't anybody tell me I didn't raise `PropertyChanged`).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

...blah blah blah...

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    Header="Date Text" 
    >
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringFormatConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Date" />
            <Binding 
                Path="DataContext.DateFormat" 
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

C#:

This will apply any string format to any value, not just a `DateTime`. My `DateFormat` property is returning `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"`.

The first binding on this converter is the value you want to format.

The second binding is a [format string parameter for `String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting). The above format string takes the "zeroth" parameter after the format string -- that's `{0}` -- and, if that value is a `DateTime`, formats it with a four digit year, a dash, a two digit month, a dash, and a two digit day. `DateTime` format strings are a subject unto themselves; [here's the MSDN page on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

What I've given you is the simplest way to write this, and by a vast margin the most powerful. You can pass in a double and give it a format string like `"My cast has {0:c} toes"` and if the double is `3.00999`, it'll tell you its cat has `$3.01` toes.

However, in giving you all the power of `String.Format()`, I've somewhat complicated the business of writing your format strings. It's a tradeoff.

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, 
        Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Format((String)values[1], values[0]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, 
        Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You answer is perfect. I deleted mine. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a problem with the formatting line? It doesn't format properly. Gives me "3/6/2017 2:28:26 AM" for your format string. The rest of the answer works perfectly though.

Comment: @TerryAnderson I don't understand. If as you say it's not formatting the date according to the format string, it's not doing anything perfectly -- in fact it's doing nothing. The code is copied and pasted from my working test case. Let me double check the format string though.

Comment: @TerryAnderson That format string is working for me with that converter and a DateTime. I just confirmed that it works with a nullable DateTime as well.

Comment: Ok, it is working with DateTime, my bad. But do I need to change it to work for double? For instance I also tried to format a double with "0.00" but it keeps giving me 0.00 instead of say 2.55.

Comment: @TerryAnderson That's because "0.00" isn't a valid [format string for `String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). It's just a string that says "0.00". Try `"{0:c}"` with a double or a decimal. Look at the code: It's the first parameter to `String.Format()`.

Comment: @TerryAnderson Added an update to the answer that I think should clarify how the thing is to be used, and what it can be used for.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I'm so used to using ,ToString() that I was confused about the string.Format().

Comment: @TerryAnderson Oh ok. That might actually be a better way of doing it, because it saves you the trouble of doing the curly brace thing. The trouble is IIRC object doesn't have an override of tostring that takes a parameter. So then you're messing around with reflection or something to get the version of the two string method that you really want to call.