# WPF Format Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I want to be able to show a distance in both metric and imperial units.However changing the unit system through a ComboBox isn't changing the format of the label.

Some details:

1) The data context is working fine

2) I get "4.00 km" when I start the program but changing the Combobox's value has no effect.

3) ObservableObject has OnPropertyChanged() and it's also working fine everywhere except here.

WPF UI

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UnitSystems}" SelectedValue="{Binding Units}"/>
<Label Content="{Binding Distance}" ContentStringFormat="{Binding DistanceFormat}"/>
```

C# View Model

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private double distance = 4;
    public double Distance
    {
        get
        {
            return distance;
        }
        set
        {
            distance = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Distance");
        }
    }

    private UnitSystem units;

    public List<UnitSystem> UnitSystems
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<UnitSystem>((UnitSystem[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(UnitSystem)));
        }
    }

    public UnitSystem Units
    {
        get
        {
            return units;
        }
        set
        {
            units = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Units");
            OnPropertyChanged("DistanceFormat");
            OnPropertyChanged("Distance");
        }
    }

    public string DistanceFormat
    {
        get
        {
            if (Units == UnitSystem.Metric)
                return "0.00 km";
            else
                return "0.00 mi";
        }
    }
}

public enum UnitSystem
{
    Metric,
    Imperial
}
```

Edit: The multibinding solution below has the same problem and it's not because of the format strings. Using f3 and f4, I start with "4.000" and it doesn't change to "4.0000".

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UnitSystems}" SelectedValue="{Binding Units}"/>
    <Label>
        <Label.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FormatConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Distance"/>
                <Binding Path="DistanceFormat"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
```

Edit 2 (SOLVED): The problem was that ObservableObject didn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged and surprisingly worked fine until this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `Units` to `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding UnitSystems}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Units}"
    />
```

`SelectedValue` is used when you use `SelectedValuePath="SomePropertyName"` to specify a property of the selected item that you care about. But enums have no properties, so just grab the item itself.

Here's my stand-in for `ObservableObject`:

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

Nothing clever. I create those with a snippet.

Comment: Hmm. I tested something similar a few days ago [for another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42604090/424129). IIRC, `ContentStringFormat` doesn't update properly properties update. Try some breakpoints. It should now be hitting the Units setter correctly when the combo selection changes; is it hitting getters for Distance *and* DistanceFormat when PropertyChanged is raised on those two in the Units setter? You may be stuck doing something with a valueconverter. Or some goofy thing like a FormattedDistance property, less work then the converter but goofy.

Comment: Actually this is not working with a multibinding too, I have the same problem with the solution in that question. I added breakpoints to the getters of Distance and DistanceFormat and no they're not being called when I use the combobox even though Units's setter is getting called.

Comment: Let me copy your code and try it. `ObservableObject` I presume is a garden-variety viewmodel base?

Comment: Yes, it's just the standard OnPropertyChanged. I'll add the one with the multibinding to the question too.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works perfectly for me exactly as you have it, except with your `SelectedValue` changed to `SelectedItem` in the XAML. Getters are hit and the unit changes in the label.

Comment: So the question is, what's different? Something must be.

Comment: That's strange. The only other thing I have is DataContext=new ViewModel() in the constructor of MainWindow. Can this be a problem with Visual Studio? Also does it work with "SelectedItem"? (although it doesn't for me.)

Comment: Yes, SelectedItem. I had the same line with the viewmodel constructor in my code behind. If the combo populated for you, you had to have had that or an equivalent, so it didn't seem worth mentioning.

Comment: With the converter, note that it takes an entire String.Format format string: "{0:f3} km" or whatever. I was lazy writing it.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot then. I guess the problem is with Visual Studio or my computer and not the code. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: It's something in the code, somewhere. I suspect there's something "irrelevant" you're not mentioning. I've answered an awful lot of these questions, and debugged a mountain of XAML. Also what is the exact format string you're giving the converter?

Comment: Your ObservableObject actually solved the problem. The only thing I omitted :D

Comment: @TerryAnderson No way. That's a relief. How'd it differ from yours?!

Comment: Wow, the difference is that my ObservableObject doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. My old ObservableObject also works.

Comment: That would do it.